# Remove array if any element is empty

Tags: php, arrays

My array is of following structure. It is a array of files submitted through form. I have multiple input fields for form. However if the user leave some field blank, the array will be displayed like below. 
I am then writing it to my database. I dont want the empty fields to be written.

I tried using `array_filter()` function, but it will not work since my array is not completely empty. The error element is set to `4`. How do i do it?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => stock-photo-cup-icons-tea-and-coffee-raster-version-109119257.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpqWWM9X
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 30609
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an (optional) callback to [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$filteredArray = array_filter($source, function($item) {
    return ($item['size'] > 0 && $item['error'] === 0);
});

var_dump($filteredArray);
```

Demo: http://codepad.viper-7.com/uocPT6

Answer (score 0):

This simple script:

```
foreach ($array as &$a) {
    $todel = false;
    foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
        if (empty($v)) { // condition to consider a variable empty
            $todel = true; break;
        }
    }
    if ($todel) unset($a);
}
```

should work fine. I think that code pretty much explains itself. What we are doing is going in a foreach loop in `$array` (the main array) and checking if the `$a` subarrays (passed by reference) has any empty value. If so we are setting `$todel = true` (and `break;` for efficiency) that will unset the current `$a` sub array.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0;$i<count($theArray);$i++)
{
    if($theArray[$i]['error']==4) 
    { 
        unset($theArray[$i]); 
    }
}
```

I would do it like that

Comment: `unset($theArray[$i]; ` to `unset($theArray[$i]);`  I edited this, but it still shows a syntax error

Comment: Just tested it and it works

Answer (score -1):

Use a simple condition

```
if(error == 0){
    //insert here
}else{
   //do nothing
}
```